# Which permissions are needed for create Azure devops test plan?

Tags: azure-devops

I was "Basic" user in Azure devops and I have started Basic+Test Plan free trial version. I can see Test plan in the menu. But When I going to Test plan page, cannot see Add Test plan button. I see only test plan that is created from before. I went detail old test plan, there is no add Test Suite button. How can I give permission for seeing the Add test plan button? Could you help me, please?

I share my screenshot as like following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjz7R.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfjSh.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Which permissions are needed for create Azure devops test plan?

As far as I know, there are two possibilities for this issue.

1. You have enable the `Basic+Test Plan` free trial, but you do not change your access from `Basic` to `Basic + Test Plans`(Make sure `Basic+Test Plan` free trial period has not expired):

   Go to the `Organization Settings`-> `Users`-> Select your account and change the access level from `Basic` to `Basic + Test Plans`:

   [image]
2. You are no permission to manage test plan, go to the `Project Settings`->`Project configuration`-> `Areas`->`Security`, check if you have permission to manage test plans and suites:

   [image]